# "No target url" in REST response

Tags: soql, rest-api

I'm using the REST API to make the following SOQL query:

```
https://<instance_name>.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/queryAll?q=SELECT+WhoId,+WhatId,+Account.Name,+Who.Name,+What.Name,+Id,+AccountId+FROM+Task+WHERE+Id+IN+('<TASK_ID_1>','<TASK_ID_2>',...,'<TASK_ID_22>')
```

Where `<TASK_ID_1>` ... `<TASK_ID_22>` are 22 different Task Ids. This usually works fine but for one specific customer the response from the query is just the string `No target url` (just the string, without JSON formatting).

The same query works just fine for many other customers, and other queries for this specific customer work as well. What may be the cause for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the error was caused by an external proxy service that was used to make the request. Fixed the issue with the proxy and the problem was solved.